# How to remap in launch file[error]

Tags: ros, roslauch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am running Ubuntu 14.04. I've successfully installed ROS Indigo. I have also set up the catkin workspace from ROS tutorials successfully. I have installed two packages from package 1 and whycon from https://github.com/lrse/whycon.git and https://github.com/simmubhangu/task_1.git(package 1). Then i run commands roslaunch task_1 task_1_1.launch. It launches the gazebo world. Then I had to remap a topic /main/image_raw to whycon. There is a whycon.launch file I have to remap the /whycon/image_out topic /main/image_raw but when i add the following code

```
<node name="image_view" pkg="gazebo" type="/main/image_raw" respawn="false" output="screen">
<remap from="image" to="/whycon/image_out"/>
<param name="autosize" value="true" />
</node>
```

Topic /main/image_raw is published by node /gazebo.When I run roslaunch whycon whycon.launch the error says cant find node gazebo. But in rosnode list there is a node /gazebo. I am new to ros , so any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275652/how-to-remap-in-launch-file%5Berror%5D/) by [alienmonster](https://answers.ros.org/users/32595/alienmonster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rather than editing someone else's package that's under source control, why not just edit your own package? When the `whycon` package gets updated (and it probably will because it looks active) anything that you changed in there will be gone when you update (pull) it. If you change files in your own package then you don't have to worry about that because you're in control.

Now, on to the solution. The topic names get defined in your `task_1_1.world` file. You have two options:

1. add a `remap` tag to your `task_1.launch` (easiest/best)
2. change your world file (still easy).

**Option 1: add a `remap` tag**

Because the topic names are defined in your world file you should add the `remap` tag *before* the `include` of the `gazebo` node:

```
<launch>
    <remap from="/main/image_raw" to="/camera/image_raw"/> <!-- Add this line -->
    <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
        <arg name="world_name" value="$(find task_1)/world/task_1_1.world"/>
        <arg name="headless" value="true"/>
        <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
        <arg name="verbose" value="true"/>
    </include>
</launch>
```

More information about launch files and remapping can be found in [the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap).

**Option 2: modify world file**

The topic names get defined in your `task_1_1.world` file on line 113:

```
<plugin name='camera_control' filename='libgazebo_ros_camera.so'>
  <cameraName>/main_camera</cameraName>
  <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
  <updateRate>60</updateRate>
  <imageTopicName>/main/image_raw</imageTopicName>
  <cameraInfoTopicName>/main/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
  <frameName>main_camera</frameName>
</plugin>
```

change

```
<imageTopicName>/main/image_raw</imageTopicName>
<cameraInfoTopicName>/main/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
```

to

```
<imageTopicName>/camera/image_raw</imageTopicName>
<cameraInfoTopicName>/camera/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
```

Now run `rostopic list` and you'll see that you have

```
/camera/camera_info
/camera/image_raw
/camera/image_raw/compressed
/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw/theora
/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
```

and you can save two versions of your world file and you can pick and choose which one you want to use. However, option 1 is (in my opinion) better.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4